# how to set cornerRadius for RoundedRectagle only bottom-left,bottom-right of a UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uibezierpath

I tried to set button bottom rounded rectangle. But they apply only Right of bottom.

I want bothside bottom of button has rounded rectangle.
This is my code:

```
UIBezierPath *shapePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:registerbtn.bounds
                                                    byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight
                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(9.0, 9.0)];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.frame = registerbtn.bounds;
shapeLayer.path = shapePath.CGPath;    
[registerbtn.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine. just try it

```
UIBezierPath *shapePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:registerbtn.bounds
                                                byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight)
                                                      cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(9.0, 9.0)];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.frame = registerbtn.bounds;
shapeLayer.path = shapePath.CGPath;

[registerbtn.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

Comment: just try this code. https://github.com/joprithiviraj/ButtonCornerRadius

Comment: @bhavin Ramani, your answer is correct but he ask only right side corner radius. So don't want to use UIRectCornerBottomLeft. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.

Just write same code in `viewWillAppear` and check:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

     [super viewWillAppear:animated];

     UIBezierPath *shapePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:registerbtn.bounds
                                                    byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight
                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(9.0, 9.0)];

     CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
     shapeLayer.frame = registerbtn.bounds;
     shapeLayer.path = shapePath.CGPath;

     [registerbtn.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}
```

Comment: Great!..HTH@user7306261

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned answers should work but the problem is your button is getting rounded from both sides but its effect is not visible to you. If you will check by zooming then you can see your button is cornered and then there is another layer under the above layer on which you have added bezierpath.

```
let shapePath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.BottomLeft,UIRectCorner.BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(8,8)) 
let newCornerLayer = CAShapeLayer()
newCornerLayer.frame = view.bounds
newCornerLayer.path = shapePath.CGPath;
view.layer.mask = newCornerLayer
```

This should work but you need to be careful on which you are applying the layer.